# How to make the image on hover attach to the mouse correctly?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem where my image previews aren't attaching to the mouse correctly. The preview is way below the mouse when I hover over the image. I need to make it so that the image display must be 15px to the right of the mouse and 15px down below the mouse. How can I achieve that? (Needs to be strictly JavaScript.)

here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pgyt1qpg/3/

here is part of the code:

```
e.target.addEventListener('mousemove', function(f) {
 var x = f.offsetX;
    y = f.offsetY;
myElement.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
myElement.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
});
```

[Preview of what the image is doing and how far away it is from the mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRmQ3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change 26th line of your JS from the linked fiddle from

```
myElement.style.top = f.offsetY + 5 + 'px';
```

to

```
myElement.style.top = f.offsetY - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(f.target).height) + 5 + 'px';
```

Why to subtract previewed image's height? Because you place the preview image below the previewed one.

See it working in [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgyt1qpg/6/).